# yii CHtml::link() vs <a href=''></a>

Tags: jquery, html, css, yii, yii-chtml

What is the best practice of using those yii  CHtml::link and such others?
I'm making a button which I need to have an icon some text and responds to hover events and it must be quite wide

Is there any advantage of using CHtml over regular  tag which I can quickly customise using some CSS and jquery?

Comment: You might as well ask, what the purpose of using a framework in the first place is, if you want to do stuff that it has designated methods for yourself …

Comment: Well on the level of MVC I understand the good side of using framework, but when it comes down to customizing small things like buttons, I don't understand what CHtml::link can give me? because it draws button in it's own style, and I want mine, so I think it's better to use straight html+css in this case no ?

Comment: Well for example it will give you automatic escaping of values where necessary. But yes, those methods are maybe more intended to handle _dynamic_ content/values (get link text form a database for example, or have the link href output dynamically according to current routing rules), whereas if you just have a static component you might as well implement that in your template in a static way as well. “It all depends” … and with such little info, there is no real saying of what might be “better” in general for the actual use case.

Comment: Well I have a regular button to make. Just a hyperlink. But a stylish hyperlink. I mean a lot of styles: size, color, etc... That's why I was wondering if CHtml can give me some advantage of styling the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either, but if you're using the framework why not use the built in methods. If you're building a stylish button in the css. Just apply it to the CHtml::link(). It also means that should your routes ever change that they will automatically be updated.